# conditional order by clause in sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query that should order the result in asc or desc depending upon a column value.

e.g.

if employee of type manager exists THEN order by joining_date, bith_date ASC
else if employee  is developer THEN order by joining_date, birth_date DESC.

I would like to achieve something like below, but can't achieve that.

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN employee_type = 'm'  
              THEN joining_date, birth_date ASC;
              WHEN employee_type = 'd' 
              THEN joining_date, birth_date  DESC;
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Well I got the answer after some research.

We can add multiple columns in where clause conditionally as follows :

```
ORDER BY DECODE(employee_type, 'm', joining_date, birth_date, salary) ASC,
         DECODE(employee_type, 'd', joining_date, birth_date, salary) DESC
```

This will order the result on the basis of employee_type.

Comment: How can this example work? The syntax of decode is: `DECODE( expression , search , result [, search , result]... [, default] )`. So it would compare employee_type with 'm' and if that does not match, it would compare employee_type with birth_date ???

Answer (score 6):

I suspect you want something like this:

```
ORDER BY 
    employee_type DESC             -- first all the managers, then the developers
                                   -- and in every one of these two groups
  , joining_date                   -- first order by joining date
  , CASE WHEN employee_type = 'm'  -- and then either by
        THEN birth_date            -- birth date ascending for managers
        ELSE NULL
    END                            -- or
  , birth_date DESC ;              -- birth date descending for the rest (devs)
```

Answer (score 0):

The question is a little bit poor specified.

> order the result in asc or desc depending upon a column value.

A column takes many values (as there are multiple rows).

Now, `order by` clause use an expression and order rows upon it.
That expression should be morphotropic(;))

So, assuming stardard oracle's employee schema, managers are:

```
select * 
from emp e
where exists (select emp_id from emp where e.id=emp.mgr_id)
```

An workaround query may be:

```
Select e.id, e.name, e.birth_date,
  case 
  when   (select count(*)  
          from emp e 
          where exists (select emp_id from  emp where e.id=emp.mgr_id)
          ) --existence of manager
    > 0 then birth_date - to_date('1-Jan-1000','dd-mon-yyyy')
    else to_date('1-Jan-1000','dd-mon-yyyy') - birth_date
   end as tricky_expression
from emp A
order by 4;
```

That exexpresion is the `case`; Using a constant(subquery that decides there are managers) it changes values from positive to negative, that is, change the order direction.

**UPDATE:** with the details in the comments:

```
select id, name, birth_date emp_type
from (
    Select id, name, birth_date, emp_type,
        case  when   cnt_mgr > 0 then birth_date - to_date('1-Jan-1000','dd-mon-yyyy')
          else to_date('1-Jan-1000','dd-mon-yyyy') - birth_date
        end as tricky_expression
    from(
        Select e.id, e.name, e.birth_date, emp_type,
           count(case when emp_type='M' then 1 else 0 end) over() as mgr_count
        from emp A
        where your_conditions
        )
     order by tricky_expression
)
where rownum=1;
```

Comment: The column values are having only employee types, i.e. either (m)anager,or (d)eveloper. So if there are manager we have to find the oldest manager in the company i.e. 

joining_date ASC WHERE RORNUM = 1;

If there are no manager then the query must return the youngest developer 

i.e. joining_date DESC WHERE ROWNUM = 1;

and this should be happened in a single query.

Comment: You should add one or two test cases to your question. But I'll update the answer with new details. The answer will be simpler.

Answer (score 0):

If there is a manager in the company this query returns the oldest manager, otherwise - the youngest developer.

```
select 
  id, name, birth_date, emp_type
from emp
where 
  id = (select 
           max(id) keep (dense_rank first order by 
             decode(emp_type, 'M', 1, 'D', 2),
             joining_date,
             decode(emp_type, 'M', 1, 'D', -1) * (birth_date - to_date('3000','yyyy')))
        from emp)
```

Comment: your are considering the birth_date only in ORDER BY clause but we have to consider the joining_date as well.