# Dynamic sorting by column depending on value in column

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle12c

Plain and simple: Is it possible to create a dynamic ordering by system, depending on the value inside the column, the query will query.

The query goes something like this:

```
SELECT id, name, sortbycolumn FROM table
WHERE id = :in_id
UNION
SELECT id, name, null sortbycolumn FROM table
WHERE id = :in_id
ORDER BY -- This part I simply don't know how to write. I have tried case and decode...
```

Comment: You would need dynamic SQL for this, meaning you would have to write a script which itself writes the SQL query and `ORDER BY` clause.

Comment: Did you see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28951746/order-by-depending-on-2-column-values), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14620931), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41939063/sort-order-by-multiple-column-values-in-oracle-in-a-case-specific-way) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13339589/custom-order-in-oracle-sql)?

Comment: If you posted sample data which illustrates what you're asking, someone might be able to assist somewhat better. Is it possible? Who knows. The way you put it, I understood it as `order by sortbycolumn` and that's most probably NOT what you meant.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include the: `CREATE TABLE` statement for your table; the `INSERT` statements for some sample data; the expected output for that sample data; an English (not code) description of the problem. You state "This part I simply don't know how to write" but you haven't explained what data you have or what output you expect so at the moment it is impossible to answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer. I did finally find the solution. It was quite simple and whilst I read through other answers, I was confused as to why it did not work for me. Apparently the index of a column will not work when using case when.

In the end, I put up the whole query with unions into a subquery with the solution being:

```
SELECT * FROM(
  SELECT id, name, sortbycolumn FROM table
  WHERE id = :in_id
  UNION
  SELECT id, name, null sortbycolumn FROM table
  WHERE id = :in_id
)
ORDER BY
    case when sortbycolumn = 1 THEN id,
    case when sortbycolumn = 2 then name
    else id end
```

Comment: This was something that came to mind, but be aware that every row in the table (or union subgroup in your case) has its own sort column, so what you finally see can look totally mixed. Also be aware that the types must match. So this would probably have to be `case when sortbycolumn = 1 then to_char(id) when sortbycolumn = 2 then name else to_char(id) end`.

Comment: Are you using `UNION [DISTINCT]` on purpose by the way. Most often you'll just want `UNION ALL` instead. The subquery is not needed by the way. The `ORDER BY` at the end of all `UNION` parts will affect the whole result.

Comment: It's supposed to be union in my case. Also order by did not work for me after the union, that's why I wrapped it all as a subquery and it worked after that... Magic.